# Insert unbounded range into TSRANGE Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, types, null, date-range

Im looking to insert an unbounded range into Postgresql TSRANGE type, according to the documentation, you set the unbounded side to null.
So I have

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Id, DateRange) 
VALUES('8C4EB534-AB33-5A7D-F378-94810C453836','[2014-07-16 00:00,NULL)')
```

Which gives me the error

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NULL"
```

Is there an issue here, or am I going about this the wrong way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `infinity`

```
VALUES('8C4EB534-AB33-5A7D-F378-94810C453836','[2014-07-16 00:00, infinity)')
```

or omit it

```
VALUES('8C4EB534-AB33-5A7D-F378-94810C453836','[2014-07-16 00:00,)')
```

which is equivalent to using the null value in the constructor

```
VALUES('8C4EB534-AB33-5A7D-F378-94810C453836', tsrange('2014-07-16 00:00',NULL, '[)'))
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INFINITE